# DOM loading and referencing elements from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

Dealing with some legacy code atm and I have an extremely annoying issue with `Javascript` and Internet Explorer.

The setup of the GUI consist of several lines of HTML printed with document.write() (from a .js file) and some work inside Javascript functions.

In the Javascript functions, the DOM does not seem to be loaded fully, because simple statements like `this.domInputObj.setAttribute(a,b)` yield an error of `setAttribute` called on a invalid element.

### A.js

```
//Some where in the beginning we print an input field with document.write
document.write('<input ...');
...
new SomeObject(document.forms[formA].inputFieldA)
```

### B.js

```
function SomeObject(inputFieldObj) {
    // the text input field
    this.inputObjFieldObj = inputFieldObj;
    this.inputFieldObj.setAttribute('a','b') //e.g. yields error in IE
}
```

My question regards how this can happen in IE only? I thought it was something with the loading order of the .js files (it might still be) and that other browsers are 'smarter'?

If I debug then the `document.write` happen before the Javascript calls, but is it buffered somehow?

Many thanks for any ideas.

## Edit

Clarified B.js. Also the alphabetical naming does not imply loading order.

Comment: You have a parameter `inputFieldObj`, but are trying to access it as `this.inputFieldObj`. That'll fail in all browsers, unless your `this` value happens to also have that same property that happens to always point to whatever is being passed.

Comment: ...and there's a real shortage of information in this question. If `A.js` is loaded before `B.js`, there'll be no `SomeObject()` function for `A.js` to invoke.

Comment: If it works in other browsers than IE, the files are loading correctly, no?

Comment: You're not providing any useful information. Your edit makes no difference. You've posted a tiny bit of vague code. If you want help, provide a minimal yet fully working example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: ...and so you're saying that `B.js` loads first, even though you gave alphabetical names to the scripts *and* put `B.js` on the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this usually happens in IE 6/7 when you are trying to dynamically create an element e.g. with your `document.write('<input ...')` statement, and then manipulate/style it with `setAttribute` instead of just manipulating the object.  Older versions of IE don't update the DOM and other internal properties to recognize that these dynamic elements have been added, hence the errors.

I would try this instead, as an example:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');

// Add a CSS class to it
input.className = "yourClass";

// Add a CSS rule to it
input.style.color = "#FF0000";
```

Instead of

```
document.write('<input type="text" id="input1" />');
document.getElementById('input1').setAttribute('class','yourClass');
document.getElementById('input1').setAttribute('color','#FF0000');
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. The problem may require 'requireJS'.